# Apache Poi MS word document goes blank when try to insert footer

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi there I coded out an application in java
which is able to create an MS word .doc file
and insert tables, images and text

However, I run into errors when I try to insert the page numbers in the footer
Error: The whole ms-word document goes blank when i run the application

Code for inserting into footer:

```
 public void addPicture(ResumeData resumeData) {
 try {
         document = new CustomXWPFDocument(
                new FileInputStream(
                        new File(


  "C:\\workoutput\\assignment2\\Resume3\\ResumeTables.doc")));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(


   "C:\\workoutput\\assignment2\\Resume4\\ResumeTables.doc"));
        String id = document.addPictureData(new FileInputStream(new File(


    "C:\\workoutput\\assignment2\\Resume3\\header.jpg")),
                Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        document.createPicture(id,


       document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG),
                640, 94);

String text = "Page1";
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
        if (policy == null) {
            policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc);
        }

        CTP ctP1 = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
        CTR ctR1 = ctP1.addNewR();
        CTText t = ctR1.addNewT();
        t.setStringValue(text);
        XWPFParagraph codePara = new XWPFParagraph(ctP1, document);

        XWPFParagraph[] newparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
        newparagraphs[0] = codePara;

        policy.createFooter(policy.DEFAULT, newparagraphs);

 }//end of try
 catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace(); 
   }

  }
```

I have been intensely google for help regarding inserting footer into ms-word document
however, there are little resources online regarding inserting footer into ms-word

please help

Comment: I am trying to insert footer rather than header

Comment: It's almost exactly the same process - headers and footers are the same kinds of thing in Word